# Try to get PHP session user into JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the user session from a PHP script into jQuery, but the result is empty. If I use the code in a PHP script it is working properly.

How can I make this work?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(
   function(){
       var user = '<?php echo $_SERVER['LOGON_USER']; ?>';

       alert(user);
       $('#answer83148X78X346').val(user);
   }
);
</script>
```

Comment: The code should work fine. The problem must be in a different part of your application

Comment: Probably, instead of $_SERVER['LOGON_USER'] you should try to use $_SESSION['LOGON_USER'].

Comment: What happens if `LOGON_USER` contains a single quote, I wonder? )

Comment: yep, @raina77ow is right. use `addslashes($_SESSION['LOGON_USER'])`

Comment: @NikitaBaksalyar you should answer this

Comment: @hek2mgl Actually, I meant something like... `var user = <?= json_encode($_SESSION['LOGON_USER']) ?>;`.

Comment: Even better :) .. Why the hell nobody answers this post? :) No need for upvotes? :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Done. Now I'm waiting for my upvotes! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want first try to check whether the variable you're using is correct by logging an output of `$_SESSION['LOGON_USER']` or whatnot. In this case, you can easily do this by checking the resulting HTML page's source code.

Also, when serializing values for JavaScript you should escape them to prevent [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) - i.e., filter value through [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function - or better serialize it as [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), because it handles all types of values, not only strings.

Comment: +1 done ..... :) But you should use `$_SESSION['LOGON_USER']` instead of `$_SERVER`

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

1. i created a authuser.php with the following code:
2. then i retrieved via jquery.get the result from authuser.php and set the textfield with this data:

   $( document ).ready(function() {

   $.get("authuser.php", function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
     $('#answer83148X78X346').val(data);
   });